# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to perform simple unit test but still it throws null or some strange error like:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Ticket cannot be returned by findById()
findById() should return Optional
```

Why is that? Instead code will event not compile.

Test looks like that:

```
@Test
void updateTicketByOrderAmount() {

    OrderedTicket orderedTicket = OrderedTicketDatasource.getOrderedTicket();

    Ticket ticket = TicketDatasource.getTicket();

    when(ticketRepository.findById(ticket.getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(ticket));

    when(ticketService.findById(ticket.getId())).thenReturn(ticket);

    Ticket actual = ticketService.updateTicketByOrderAmount(orderedTicket);

    assertNotNull(actual);

}
```

and implementation:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Ticket updateTicketByOrderAmount(OrderedTicket orderedTicket) {
        Ticket found = findById(orderedTicket.getTicket().getId());

        decreaseInStockAmount(orderedTicket, found);

        return ticketMapper.ticketDTOtoTicket(
                saveOrUpdateTicket(
                        ticketMapper.ticketToTicketDTO(found)
                )
        );
    }

 @Override
    public Ticket findById(Long id) {
        return ticketRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);
    }


 private void decreaseInStockAmount(OrderedTicket ticket, Ticket found) {
        found.setInStock(
                found.getInStock() - ticket.getAmount()
        );
    }
```

Full stacktrace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Ticket cannot be returned by findById()
findById() should return Optional
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.


    at server.eventooserver.api.v1.service.TicketServiceImplTest.updateTicketByOrderAmount(TicketServiceImplTest.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

It points directly to

```
when(ticketService.findById(ticket.getId())).thenReturn(ticket);
```

But why is that?

What is more I am attaching how mock are initialized:

```
   @Mock
    TicketRepository ticketRepository;

    TicketService ticketService;

    public TicketServiceImplTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ticketService = new TicketServiceImpl(ticketRepository);
    }
```

I know that ticketService is not Mock but if I will remove this line it will throw:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not <null>

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:38)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.failNull(AssertNotNull.java:47)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:36)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:258)
    at server.eventooserver.api.v1.service.TicketServiceImplTest.updateTicketByOrderAmount(TicketServiceImplTest.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

And screenshot from debugger 
[image]

Comment: So which one returns `Optional<Ticket>`, `TicketService.findById` or `TicketRepository.findById`?

Comment: TicketRepository returns Optional of Ticket  where TicketService returns just Ticket

Comment: "I know that ticketService is not Mock but if I will remove this line it will throw..". Yes, but you have to remove the line. Because it's **not** a mock yet you're trying to mock a method call on it. Your root problem is the last stacktrace, i.e. why is `null` returned.

Comment: I know but  other methods where this repository method is used passes.

Comment: Did you remove the `when(ticketService.findById(ticket.getId())).thenReturn(ticket);` line already? You're not going to get anywhere if you don't remove it.

Comment: Yes, I have removed it and still null is thrown.

Comment: Good. At least now you've found your real problem. Now it's time for you to debug why `null` is returned (not thrown).

Comment: I have attached screenshot from debugger also.

Comment: Found the solution, this was Lombok issue. Thank you @Kayaman

Answer (score 0):

**Changes to be made:**

1. `thenReturn(Optional.of(ticket));`

The argument inside `thenReturn` because of `Optional.of()` cannot be `null`. Instead use `Optional.ofNullable(T value)`. Returns an Optional describing the specified value, if non-null, otherwise returns an empty.

2. Change `when(ticketService.findById(ticket.getId())).thenReturn(ticket);` to `doReturn(ticket).when(ticketService).findById(ticket.getId())`

> Read This:
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mockito/9WUvkhZUy90

Comment: Not the root cause, since this involves a spy and calling the real method.

Comment: Thank you but now it is thrown: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();